# Django Post.objects.all() does not show object

Tags: django

Hi I'm learning Django based on the Django girls tutorial.
I'm stuck in chapter 9 when I am trying to display all of my Post objects in the python shell.

> `from blog.models import Post`
>   `Post.objects.all()`

It should display

`[<Post: Title>, <Post: Title2>]`

but instead it displays

`[<Post: Post object>, <Post: Post object>]`

I was trying to find the solution for this but all say may be the cause of the error is in the models.py.
I checked my *blog\models.py* and it seems to be good. It contains `__str__` method with the indentation.
I'm using Python 3.6.0 and Dajngo 1.11.6. Please help me
    My blog/models.py is the following

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)

def publish(self):
    self.published_date = timezone.now()
    self.save()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Comment: You have an indentation problem with publish and __str__ funtions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your model class. class and functions are both in same alignment.  It should be

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: @Zuggi, can you please accept the answer if the answer solved your problem.

Comment: I checked they are the same alignment.

Comment: it is returning full object instead specific field. You must return as string. Can you please check again.

Comment: I've compared my code to the original tutorial code and they are the same.
Here is the link for the tutorials.
https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_models/

Comment: can you please provide tutorial link

Comment: Problem should be indentation. I have checked and also mentioned in tutorial. 
Also notice that both def publish(self): and def __str__(self): are indented inside our class. Because Python is sensitive to whitespace, we need to indent our methods inside the class. Otherwise, the methods won't belong to the class, and you can get some unexpected behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your help. You are absolutely right the cause of the problem was the indentation.